# Duda sobre clonar un objeto

Tags: python, poo

tengo que crear un método el cuál clone un objeto de la clase rectángulo, el tema es que al invocar el método no me da los atributos del nuevo rectángulo a pesar de haber hecho el método str , sino que me dice main.object......
mi código es este:

```
class punto:
    def __init__(self):
        self.posx=20
        self.posy=40

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"posx: '{self.posx}' posy : {self.posy}")

class rectangulo:
    def __init__(self,alto,largo,color):
        self.verticeizquierdo=punto()
        self.alto=alto
        self.largo=largo
        self.color=color
    def area(self):
        area=self.largo*self.alto/2
        return area

    def tamaño(self,x):
        if x>1:
            self.largo=self.largo*x
            self.alto=self.alto*x
        else:
            self.largo=self.largo/x
            self.alto=self.alto/x
        return self.largo,self.alto

    def vertices(self):
        verticesuperorizquierdo=self.verticeizquierdo
        verticesuperiorderecho=20


    def clonar(self):
        nuevorectangulo=rectangulo(self.alto,self.largo,self.color)
        return nuevorectangulo


    def __str__(self):
         return (f"alto : '{self.alto}' largo : {self.largo}: color : {self.color} daño : ")
        



mirectangulo=(rectangulo(20,60,"rojo"))
print(mirectangulo.clonar)
```

me gustaría saber una manera que al invocarlo me devuelva un objeto rectángulo igual al anterior ya creado

Comment: Lo correcto es `print(mirectangulo.clonar())`. Te falta el `()`. Lo que estás imprimiendo es el **método** `clonar`, no el resultado de la ejecución de `clonar()`

Comment: Gracias, no puedo creer que la razón por la que no me funcionaba era tan simple.

Answer (score 0):

es muy facil lo unico que tienes que hacer es poner el `.clonar` con parentesis al final,`.clonar()`

de todos modos si te ayudo valora la respuesta :)